# Raphael.js Qtip tooltip disappears when trying to set id

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael, qtip, qtip2

I'm using [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.circle) and [qTip](http://qtip2.com/demos) together to show a tooltip when hovering over the circle I draw with raphael.

It works, until I try to give the Raphael element an id, then the tooltip just doesn't show up.

Works:

```
var c = self.paper.circle(x, y, radius)
.attr({'fill':'#f2f2f2'});
$(c.node).qtip({content:{text:circleName}});
```

Does not work:

```
var c = self.paper.circle(x, y, radius)
.attr({'fill':'#f2f2f2'})
.id = circleName; //<---
$(c.node).qtip({content:{text:circleName}});
```

ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I simplify the way you give the id, it becomes this:

```
var c = a.id = circleName;
```

Because of the second `=`, `c` is not a `circle` element, and the tooltip cannot be shown, it does not know where.

If you set the id after creating the circle...

```
var c = self.paper.circle(x, y, radius)
.attr({'fill':'#f2f2f2'});

c.id = circleName;

$(c.node).qtip({content:{text:circleName}});
```

... the problem disappears.

I created a [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/eCOqUDu/2/edit) to show you (not exactly the same code but it should be enough).